# mod_rewrite: remove www and trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, isapi

I already have a rule set up to remove www from my urls and redirect them...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://'%'1$1 [R=301,L]
```

*note-I had to put quotes around the percent sign to post this message, the actual rule does not contain them.

I now want to also strip off any trailing /

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```